# Query CUstom Record using Custom Field in Mulesoft

Tags: netsuite, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I want to query a custom record based on the custom field in the custom record in Anypoint Studio. I tried using Search operation in Netsuite but it seems that I unable to write the dataweave code accordingly.

I used the code below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    customFieldList: {
        customField: [{
            internalId: "8",
            scriptId: "abc"
        } as Object {
            class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.ListOrRecordRef"
        } ]
    } as Object {
        class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.CustomFieldList"
    },
    recType: {
        internalId: "10078"
    }
} as Object {
    class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.CustomRecordSearchBasic"
}
```

I used basic Custom record search.I am getting below error

```
Message               : null
Element               : testFlow2/processors/0 @ test:test.xml:18 (Transform Message)
Element DSL           : <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="c6dbb0ee-4979-4667-bab1-e0b5d72a6b2b">
                        <ee:message>
                        <ee:set-payload>%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    customFieldList: {
        customField: [{
            internalId: "8",
            scriptId: "abc"
        } as Object {
            class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.ListOrRecordRef"
        } ]
    } as Object {
        class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.CustomFieldList"
    },
    recType: {
        internalId: "10078"
    }
} as Object {
    class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.CustomRecordSearchBasic"
}</ee:set-payload>
                        </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
FlowStack             : at testFlow2(testFlow2/processors/0 @ test:test.xml:18 (Transform Message))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.exception.CannotInstantiateException.message(CannotInstantiateException.scala:7)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.parser.exception.LocatableException.getMessage(LocatableException.scala:18)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.parser.exception.LocatableException.getMessage$(LocatableException.scala:15)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.exception.CannotInstantiateException.getMessage(CannotInstantiateException.scala:6)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.dataweave.DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor$1.handledException(DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor.java:298)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.dataweave.DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor$1.evaluate(DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor.java:309)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:105)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.SetPayloadTransformationTarget.process(SetPayloadTransformationTarget.java:32)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.TransformMessageProcessor.lambda$0(TransformMessageProcessor.java:92)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.TransformMessageProcessor.process(TransformMessageProcessor.java:92)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedFunction.apply(CheckedFunction.java:25)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.rx.Exceptions.lambda$checkedFunction$2(Exceptions.java:84)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.rx.Operators.lambda$nullSafeMap$0(Operators.java:47)
    at reactor.core.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.* (2 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
    at reactor.core.* (6 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much. But I figured it some how. I got the solution to it. But I can accept other solutions too. I just added a class and it worked.

Thank you again.

Comment: What did you do to resolve this please?